# Who/what is the Embedded?

Tags: dark-souls-2

There is very little that I have found on this topic, like Pharros the Vagabond and Alva the Wayfarer.

All that is clear about the Embedded is the description of the Key to the Embedded:

> Sword that opens the Embedded's door.
>   Shaped like a weapon, but is in fact a key.
>   Plunge the key into the Embedded
>   to bring a rhapsodic end to his fate.
>
> The once-human Embedded, realizing that he
>   could never resist the temptation of the flesh,
>   bound himself eternally with chains. Since then,
>   he has awaited the day that somebody will
>   find this key, and bury it within his bosom.

The whole thing is just disturbing, and just a touch Freudian. However nothing about it sheds any light on the matter. There are theories that he is Alva, and other theories that he is Pharros (though personally I think the theory about him being part of the Rotten makes more sense).

Comment: I find it interesting that you call the description "rape-y", when describes a person restraining theirself from "the temptation of the flesh" and then willingly awaited someone finding the key and stabbing him. More relevant to the question, given how sparse Dark Souls II lore is, it's likely that your answer will be "there is no more information about the Embedded."

Comment: I agree with murgatroid99. If you can't find direct evidence and/or clues that give indirect hints, there will be no *definite* answer. Maybe some hints will be given as to who the Embedded is in the upcoming DLC content but I doubt it. Hurrah for obscurity!

Comment: I understand there is no one true definite answer (unless it's from the dev's themselves). However there are additional hints to most things in the collector's guide that I am unable to access. Basically I guess I'm asking "What's your theory?"

Comment: And also, while it's still disputed because there is no single answer in most cases, lore questions are still allowed. http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5522/can-i-make-questions-about-lore-in-arqade

Comment: You are right, lore question *are* allowed. I was not trying to imply that this question was not allowed, only that you shouldn't have high expectations for an answer. However, "What's your theory?" questions are definitively disallowed as "primarily opinion based".

Comment: @Ben - As far as I know there wasn't anything about the Embedded in the collecters guide. Unfortunately I have no theory about who he is other than some poor SOB who probably made the wrong decision :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Embedded](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Embedded) can be found in Dangleic Castle, at the top of a long elevator.  The elevator is located just past the third area bonfire.

The Embedded is blocking the way to a cell holding one of the [Milfanito](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Milfanito), who will give you the [Ring of the Dead](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Ring+of+the+Dead) if you free her.

Aside from the description of the key in-game, there is no other text about this character, although one of the wiki sites has the following description:

> The Embedded was once a man, who was tempted greatly by flesh, and knowing that he could not resist it, created his mask and the Key to the Embedded and waited for someone to find his key and bring him to his end.

[image: The Embedded]

Comment: Cue the most awkward animation in the game.